# What is bigger than 'unsigned long long int' in C++ (Visual Studio)?

Tags: c++

What is bigger than `unsigned long long int` in C++ (Visual Studio)?

`fib(93)` doesn't work, but `fib(92)` works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long int fib(int n) {
    unsigned long long * f = new unsigned long long int[n];
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2];
    }
    return f[n-1];
}

int main() {
    cout << fib(93);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's potentially quite a large memory leak. :-)

Comment: there is no integer built in type bigger than that

Comment: Well, `unsigned long long[2]` is bigger than `unsigned long long` (i.e. takes more space), but I guess you were looking for an unsigned integral type that has a greater maximum value than `unsigned long long`... Btw: To calculate a single fibonacci value, you just need store 2 intermediate values; you don't need to keep all the numbers you never touch again...

Comment: suggested solution  ?

Comment: The suggested solution is to use an arbitrary precision numeric library instead of built-in types.

Comment: See also "[biggest integer datatype in c++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1417113/90527)"

Comment: I am impressed by the number of programming beginners that want to use huge integer numbers. I have been programming in C++ for more than 20 years, and I *never* felt any need to use an arbitrary precision library. Well, for hashing, I wish I could use `uint128_t`, but otherwise, 64-bit integers seem to much longer than necessary nearly always.

Comment: @prapin I think it's class problems and code challenges that require those really big integers, nothing in real life. A little known fact is that a double floating point can hold a 53 bit integer; JavaScript doesn't bother having an integer type.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no *native* integer type larger than `(unsigned) long long int` defined by the C++ standard. Some compilers do implement a custom 128-bit integer type as an extension (`__(u)int128_t`, etc), but that is not standard. There are plenty of big-integer libraries readily available that implement arbitrary-length integers.